# Google Places API in Android app : getGoogleAppId failed with status 10

Tags: android, google-places-api

I am using the Google Places api in my Android app. I'm using the Place picker specifically. 
I registered my app in the Google services console, enabled the Google Play API, generated my key and added in to my manifest, along with the Fine_Location permission. Basically, I did all the steps in the documentation, however I get this error in my log:

getGoogleAppId failed with status: 10

I am not sure if the key is not right, I read that it might be because my app is not registered user Debug mode, if so, how do I do that in the GSConsole? Any help would be much appreciated!!

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same error. If you're referring to a debug vs. release certificate for the SHA-1 fingerprint, this doc has details: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue which was fixed for me by installing the Google Play Services SDK.

In Android Studio -

- Tools->Android->SDK Manager
- select 'SDK Tools' Tab
- select Google Play Services tick box

I was trying out the [Barcode API of Mobile Vision](https://developers.google.com/vision/barcodes-overview) and got the same issue.

Google Places API is also part of [Google Play Services](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/start#api-overview) and might also be your problem.

Hope this works for you too!